# JavaScript - Negative byte from integer

Tags: javascript, encoding, integer, byte

I transmit a byte that's always less than 127 with a 1 bit flag to the client by ORing the byte with 0x80.

On the client side, in JavaScript, I have an Array() of numbers representing the bytes of the message (yes it's probably dumb but I haven't figured out typed arrays yet).

Everything works fine until I hit a number with the highest bit of the lowest byte set.

```
Number:    0011 0101
  flag:    1000 0000
           ---------
           1011 0101


Stored as
integer in   ???
JavaScript
```

How can I retrieve the original byte (with the highest bit set to 0), plus the flag (denoted by the value of the highest bit)?

EXAMPLE:

```
(server)
byte x = 90
x | 0x80
> -38

(client - JavaScript)
var x = -38
x ^ 0x80
> -166
```

How do I get 90 back?

EDIT - I discovered this was due to another bug in my code... I wasn't going crazy with the encoding... sorry all...

Comment: Sorry, don't fully understand the question. Am I right in thinking you simply are trying to "split" the single byte into a 7-bit value and a 1-bit value?

Comment: Yes but it's not a byte anymore, it's some kind of JavaScript number. XORing with 0x80 still results in negative numbers.

Comment: Can you show the code that produces the negative number? This works for me: `num = parseInt('10110101', 2) ^ 0x80` and `flag = parseInt('10110101', 2) & 0x80 !== 0`

Comment: I've added an example to explain the problem. Thanks guys....

Comment: Try `-38 & 0xFF ^ 0x80` instead. See my answer for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19562701/783743

Answer (score 1):

Try the following in JavaScript:

```
var received = -38;
var adjusted = received & 0xFF; // 218
var original = adjusted ^ 0x80; // 90
```

That should solve your problem.

**Explanation:** All numbers in JavaScript stored in the [double-precision floating point format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format):

[image]

Bitwise operators however can't deal with floating point numbers. Hence they convert their operands into 32-bit signed integers. [[source]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators)

```
-38 = 11111111 11111111 11111111 11011010
```

Hence if you do `-38 ^ 0x80` you get the wrong answer as only the 8th bit from the right is set to `0`. You need to first limit `-38` to 8-bits before xoring it with `0x80`. Only the least significant byte (i.e. `11011010`) is needed. Hence we do `-38 & 0xFF` to get the least significant byte.

Now that you have the correct byte you may simply xor it with `0x80`.

**TLDR**: Use `byte & 0xFF ^ 0x80`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand the question, but I will give a shot: you have just to XORing the 0x80:

```
var received = 181; // 10110101
var num = received ^ 0x80;

console.log(num); // 53, 00110101
```

If you have  a different result, probably there is something different in your code – if you run the code above, should give the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing a problem.

Here is some code I've written to test, with [JSFiddle live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xs4gv/3/)

```
var val = 57;
var flag = 1;

var valWithFlag = val | (flag ? 0x80 : 0);
var newVal = (valWithFlag & 0x7F);
var newValFlag = (valWithFlag & 0x80 ? 1 : 0);

alert("Val: " + val.toString() + "\n" + 
      "Flag: " + flag.toString() + "\n" +
      "Val With Flag: " + valWithFlag.toString() + "\n" + 
      "New Val Without Flag: " + newVal.toString() + "\n" + 
      "New Val Flag: " + newValFlag.toString() + "\n");
```

It is giving the desired results...

```
Val: 57
Flag: 1
Val With Flag: 185
New Val Without Flag: 57
New Val Flag: 1
```

---

**UPDATE** based on extra details provided by the OP

I think this is probably due to integers in javascript being held either as 32 or 64 bit values... so when you pass through -38 to javascript it isn't being held in the same way as the single byte on your server.

You need to convert that -38 into an 8-byte...

```
var val = -38;
var jsVal = (val & 0xFF);
```

Which should give you your 90 value to work with. Here is an [updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xs4gv/4/)